# Edit Excel JumpList via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm desperately trying to find how I can access the JumpList via VBA.

I currently have a bit of code that rips apart an Excel file into separate sheets and saves them all separately (about 50+ sheets) This unfortunately triggers the JumpList to be updated with each individual file which gets a bit annoying especially as Excel's own 'recently used files' doesn't get updated.

What I want to do is either a) stop them being added to the Jump List or b) recreate the jump list.

Having looked around the easiest way to do this is to reference the WindowsAPICodePack. Either from it itself or the PresentationFramework Library. However I can't for the life of me find how to access these from Excel. I've seen a lot of references to 'Tools/AddIns/Automation' However I can't see that in my Office 2013. Can anyone help at all as to how I could include these references or access the JumpList

Comment: In vba a) stop  them being added can be done. About recreating, I am not sure. Let me know if just preventing the list from neing updated works for you. I will post the answer.

Comment: How can it be done? I can't find any information other then what I've detailed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBA work-around is to set the Excel's jump list file to read-only, after that whatever you do, the list is not updated. Once you are done and want to resume the list update feature just the set the file attribute as normal.

```
Sub manageJumpList(bAllowAdd As Boolean)

    Dim strJumpFile         As String

    '/ Excel's Jump Location
    strJumpFile = Environ("userprofile") & _
    "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\b8ab77100df80ab2.automaticDestinations-ms"

    If Not bAllowAdd Then
        '/Stop from updating
        SetAttr strJumpFile, vbReadOnly
     '<<After doing this, whatever files you open, they will not be added to recent list>>
    Else
        '/ Allow to update
        SetAttr strJumpFile, vbNormal
    End If

End Sub


Sub test()

    '/ Stop  Updating JumpList
    Call manageJumpList(False)

    '/ Start  Updating JumpList
    'Call manageJumpList(True)

End Sub
```